# What are those trucks towing around, and why?

Tags: airport

I was in Prague airport and saw those things going around:
[image]

As for title, what are they towing and why? I can imagine it could be to alter airport layout, but I don't see a use for it.

Sub question for and additional answer's virtual bonus: is it funny as it seems? I could imagine drifting those things around :-D

Answer (score 30, accepted):

They are called "Jersey barriers" and are temporary barriers used to alter the layout and to introduce defined lanes for vehicles, passengers etc.

For the bonus, they are not fun to tow.  If that line starts snaking, you have to stop until they all settle down before moving off again. Try drifting with those, and the weight would get so far outside your turn radius in no time flat that you'll spin the vehicle and jack-knife the lot.

[image: http://borderbarriers.co.uk/uploads/image_directories/main_gallery/med/separator-55-barrier.jpg]
[Border Barriers UK](http://borderbarriers.co.uk)<sup>©</sup>

[image: http://www.rentplasticjerseybarriers.com/images/airport-barriers-plastic-jersey.jpg]
[RentPlasticJerseyBarriers.com](http://www.rentplasticjerseybarriers.com)<sup>©</sup>

Comment: @J.Hougaard Good spot. That's worth an answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 14):

As Simon pointed out, the cars in your image appear to be towing airport barriers, which are used to visually mark areas on the aerodrome that are temporarily not available for air traffic.

They are typically used during construction work on or near runways and taxiways at an aerodrome, like in this image:

[image]

Although air crews are notified of such construction work through other means, such as NOTAM's and information from the air traffic control, the visible barriers are there to add another level of safety to prevent traffic from entering such areas. There has been a number of incidents and accidents where aircraft have entered closed areas, in spite of the fact that information of the closures was published correctly. See more here: http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Runway/Taxiway_Construction_Risks

I do not know how recent your image is. If it is recent, it may very well be related to some of the below NOTAMs, which announce closures of different areas at Prague airport:

Q) LKAA/QMXLC/IV/M /A /000/999/5006N01416E A) LKPR B) 16/09/11 09:35 C) 16/09/11 13:00 E)
**TAXILANE BTN TWY 'R' AND TWY 'P' CLSD. DAY MARKING**

Q) LKAA/QMXLC/IV/NBO /A /000/999/5006N01416E
A) LKPR
B) 16/09/08 06:00 C) 16/09/30 12:00
E) **TAXILANE FOR EXIT FROM STAND S55 AND S56 CLSD FOR ACFT TAXIING. DAY AND NIGHT MARKING.**

Q) LKAA/QMXLC/IV/M /A /000/999/5006N01416E
A) LKPR
B) 16/09/08 06:00 C) 16/09/15 10:00
E) **TWY R BTN TWY L AND ENTRY TO STAND S54 CLSD. TWY RR CLSD.DAY AND NIGHT MARKING**

Comment: I don't know why you call those *airport barriers*. There doesn't appear to be anything airport-specific about them. I've seen them in many places, especially around roadworks on motorways.

Comment: @TRiG simply because I do not know the technical name for them :)

Comment: Although they might be identical, they cannot be called road barriers in this context.